# Getting sum of elements from grouped column in sql

Tags: python, sql

[image]Database Schematic and Relationship Diagram

[image: CODE OUTPUT AFTER USING THE COUNT FUNCTION IN THE SELECT SEGMENT]

I need to get the number of movies that have both a genre description of Romantic and Comedy which involves joining the genre and movies tables however when using the GROUP BY function using the COUNT function gives you a list of elements and not the sum. How can I get the sum of items grouped?

Here is the code I used.

```
%%sql 
SELECT m.movie_id AS 'Movie Count'
FROM  movies AS m
INNER JOIN genremap AS gm
ON    m.movie_id = gm.movie_id
INNER JOIN genres AS g 
ON    gm.genre_id = g.genre_id
WHERE g.genre_name = 'Romance' 
OR    g.genre_name = 'Comedy'
GROUP BY gm.movie_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.genre_name)= 2
```

Comment: Have you tried using `COUNT()` on the SELECT instead?

Comment: Yes, I have, but that just gives a long list of elements with the value 2. So it gives a column filled with the value 2.